# Vscode shows error NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED error during startup

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I start vscode I get following errors in the output pane

```
[Error - 12:01:21] (node:32640) Warning: Setting the NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED environment variable to '0' makes TLS connections and HTTPS requests insecure by disabling certificate verification.
[Error - 12:01:21] (node:32640) Warning: Setting the NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED environment variable to '0' makes TLS connections and HTTPS requests insecure by disabling certificate verification.
```

- `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED` is not set on the system
- settings.json does not contain any setting for "tls"

How can I find what causes this ?

```
[About Window Title]
Visual Studio Code

Version: 1.47.3 (system setup)
Commit: 91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3e
Date: 2020-07-23T13:12:49.994Z (1 wk ago)
Electron: 7.3.2
Chrome: 78.0.3904.130
Node.js: 12.8.1
V8: 7.8.279.23-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.18363
```

Comment: It's shown by YAML support https://i.imgur.com/9bcC0dl.png

Answer (score 0):

I had the Swagger Viewer extension installed which depends on the Yaml Support extension.

I uninstalled both applications to get rid of the error as it was very annoying and installed an alternative to Swagger Viewer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, in my case it's probably another extension that causes this. 
Can you share how you found it was the YAML Support that caused it ?

I do have a YAML extension by RedHat https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.vscode-yaml

Comment: I had the same console output you have in your uploaded image (the dropdown option).

When I tried to remove the Yaml Support extension VS Code told me Swagger Viewer needed it so I just got shot of them both.

There is probably a better way to do it without having to remove them. I hope you find the answer - then I might get mine back.